# Debug Xcode program or watch output log

Tags: ios, xcode

Im new to Xcode programming , and i want to know is there any way to Find out program compile

and execution behavior on Xcode IDE?

I have some exprience on both Eclipse and VisualStudio IDE.

in eclipse i use Logcat for watching the output messages and error logs and Same Happens to

visual studio on Output or error list windows , but problem is i couldnt find the way to check

this log on Xcode.

there is a guid on apple site :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

and there is a log window on IOS simulator.

are these my only available option and should i only stick to them ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not relating programming

Comment: asking about how to debug a program on ide is off topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See three icon are in the Top right corner click on middle icon

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You use the *Console* in Xcode, controlled from the *Debug Area* menu:

[image]

Which looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All your Logs and errors are shown in Debug are,

You can print log using NSLog  i.e. `NSLog(@"log message");`

You can show it from
:
[image]

Or

On Top Right side
[image]

So all Errors and logs are show in Debug area.

[image]